# Permutations balanced binary trees: how can I get the $\log n$ inequalities corresponding to a leaf without computing the whole tree?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, trees

I created the (balanced?) binary tree of all length $n$ permutations in a greedy manner: for each permutation and each pair of numbers I computed whether they appear in ascending order or not, and then I proceeded to greedily select the best pair of numbers to compare so as to produce as balanced a tree as possible; this means that different levels in different branches can look at different pairs of numbers.

Here is the tree I obtained for length $4$, with $<$ meaning the two numbers appear in ascending order, and $>$ that they appear in descending order.

[image]

I haven't proven it, but indeed it appears that the depth of this greedily-constructed balanced binary tree is bounded by $\lceil \log_2 n!\rceil$, and so each permutation can be represented by at most that many comparisons about pairs of elements appearing ascending or descending.

Question #1: For a particular permutation, how could I compute the shortest list of necessary comparisons that uniquely define that permutation? I can't use the same method as I've used to construct this tree, as to balance it I needed to generate all $n!$ permutations, computation which is not feasible for large $n$; and if I don't compute all permutations I can't balance the tree and a non-balanced tree does not obey the $\lceil \log_2 n!\rceil$ bound on depth.

Question #2: Given two different permutations, which correspond to two different nodes in this tree, how could I compute the number of comparisons they agree on (out of all possible $n(n-1)/2$ comparisons)?

Question #3: can you confirm / share a link to a proof that a greedily-balanced binary tree of permutations obeys the $\lceil \log_2 n!\rceil$ bound on depth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the shallowest comparison tree to sort $n$ objects is in general an open problem. According to [the OEIS page for the optimal comparison numer](https://oeis.org/A036604), we only know these numbers up to $n=15$. Furthermore, the optimal number of comparisons to sort $12$ items is $30$, which is one more than $\lceil \log_2 12!\rceil=29$. This answers your question $3$ in the negative.

For question $1$, any permutation can be defined by $n-1$ comparisons, and no fewer. For example, when $n=5$, the permutation $[2,4,1,5,3]$ is uniquely specified by these four comparisons:
$$
2<4,\quad 4<1,\quad 1<5,\quad 5<3
$$
To see this is optimal, note that if only $n-2$ comparisons are given for the permutation $\pi=[\pi_1,\pi_2,\dots,\pi_n]$, then there must exist some $i\in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$ for which the comparison $\pi_i < \pi_{i+1}$ is not given. This implies the given comparisons cannot distinguish $\pi$ from the permutation resulting from switching $\pi_i$ and $\pi_{i+1}$ in $\pi$.

You can see the problem of finding the optimal set of comparisons to specify a permutation is trivial, and unrelated to the comparison tree.

Finally, for question $2$, given two permutations $\pi$ and $\tau$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ you want a way to compute the number of unordered pairs $\{i,j\}$ for which $\pi_i$ and $\pi_j$ appear in the same order in $\pi$ as $\tau_i$ and $\tau_j$ do in $\tau$. This is equal $\binom n2$ minus the number of inversions of $\pi\circ \tau^{-1}$. To compute this, you can

- Compute $\tau^{-1}$. This takes $O(n\log n)$ time.
- Compute $\pi\circ \tau^{-1}$. Should take $O(n)$, if you use arrays, I think?
- Compute the number of inversions of $\pi\circ \tau^{-1}$. This takes $O(n\log n)$; see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array) for the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's great! Regarding the link you posted re question 2: is it the right link? it seems to send me to something unrelated.

Comment: And may I ask you a follow-up question :) I realized after seeing your answer to question 1 that that's not what I meant to ask -- what I did mean to ask was -- for a particular permutation, how could I compute the shortest list of necessary comparisons that uniquely define that permutation using as few comparisons are possible; pretend I don't already know the order and I need to compute it; and I'm starting to think a good answer is "whatever merge sort does" -- I'm starting to think that this tree is related to merge sort, with the leaf nodes being the first comparisons merge sort performs

Comment: @Gabi My answer to question 2 proves that "computing the shortest list of comparisons that uniquely define a permutation" is equivalent to sorting the permutation, and then outputting the list of inequalities between adjacent pairs. But yeah, if you can clarify exactly what you want and post a new question, I'll take a look.